# Database schema to C++  Code Generator

Tags: c++, code-generation, database-schema

I want to know if there is an open source or proprietary software that I can use to generate a C++ code from a database schema.

Comment: What kind of code do you want, simple layer to access data or Entities for an ORM/OPF? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate classes for your tables, getters/setters for the data & inheritance/composition/aggregation for the relationships in your tables you can do this by creating a domain specific language for handling your task. Compiler-Compiler tools like lex/yacc can be of help to you. You can define a grammar (this wont be very easy task for your problem statement) and then use lex/yacc to solve your problem.